# how to calculte this multiple integrals $\iiint_G 1 dxdydz$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, integration, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$F=\{(x, y, z)\in R^3| x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1\} \\ G=\{ (2x+y+z,x+2y+z,x+y+4z)|(x, y, z)\in F\}$

$\iiint_G 1 dxdydz$

the integrand is $1$, so it represents the volume of $G$. I can calculte it directly by 
$x'=2x+y+z \\ y'=x+2y+z \\z'=x+y+4z,$

but it's a little cumbersome. Any easier way related to eigenvalues of the martix
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}
or something can be find.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant of a $3\times3$ matrix is exactly the factor by which the corresponding linear transformation changes the volume of any region of $\Bbb R^3$ (with a negative sign if it "inverts" / mirrors space). (This generalizes in the obvious way to other dimensions as well.)

So what you want is to take the determinant of your matrix and multiply by the volume of $F$. And then the absolute value of that is your answer.

Comment: How to prove it, the value of the integral is the determinant of the matrix and multiply by the volume of $F$

Comment: @UteemHumbaba You already have all the pieces here. You said yourself, the value of the integral is the volume of $G$. And your matrix (let's call it $A$) is such that $G = AF$. One of the common _definitions_ of the determinant is that it is the factor by which volumes change (but if this isn't your definition, then it is a theorem that needs to be proven). Thus the volume of $G$ is the determinant of $A$ multiplied by the volume of $F$. These are all things that either I or you have already said.